Lambda import parmiko errors with cryptography
Im trying to set up python function that uses parmiko.
Im using a mac m chip to work from.
Terraform for the module is:
module "lambda-test" {

  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws"
  version = "7.2.1"
  #architectures = ["arm64"]
  function_name = "ssh-test"
  description   = "Test pulling ssh from secrets manager and connecting to server"
  handler       = "main.lambda_handler"
  runtime       = "python3.8"
  publish       = true
  source_path   = "${path.module}/src/"
  timeout       = 300
  attach_policy = true
  policy        = aws_iam_policy.lambda-policy.arn

  vpc_subnet_ids         = [data.aws_subnets.intra.ids[0], data.aws_subnets.intra.ids[1], data.aws_subnets.intra.ids[2]]
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.sg.id]
  attach_network_policy  = true
}

data "aws_lambda_invocation" "test" {
  depends_on    = [module.lambda-test]
  function_name = module.lambda-test.lambda_function_name
  input         = <<JSON
{
    "key1": "value1"
}
 JSON
}

this loads all files in the src folder which contains the main.py file my function lives on.
To import parmiko i run pip install parmiko -t . in the src folder to download the modules locally which then get put into the function. Ive done this with other modules and its worked fine. But i cant get it work with this, getting error:
│ Error: invoking Lambda Function (ssh-test): returned error: "{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'main': /var/task/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "stackTrace": []}"

ive tried:

change the python version of the module to 3.9 and 3.8 to install using pyenv and virtualenv
using a docker image to import via: docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/app -w /app python:3.11 bash again for python3.11 and 3.9
tried using docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task -it lambci/lambda:build-python3.8 /bin/bash
changing the lambda to use architecture = arm64

But I always get the same error
Any ideas what im doing wrong?
Any ideas what im missing?
